# Add single quotes in a string array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, quotes, single-quotes

I been searching for the solution but can't find it...

I have the following array with the following output:

```
['Fruits, Cars, Clothes, Shoes']
```

But I need the that array to output the following:

```
['Fruits', 'Cars', 'Clothes', 'Shoes']
```

I already tried the following and it did not work:

```
var output= arr.map(item => "'" + item + "'").join();
```

Can you help please

Comment: `arr[0].split(", ")`

Comment: So how did the string get into that format to start which is a string, not an array? Can you fix what produces that line?

Comment: Is coming from the API, I cant make a direct change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the first (and unique) item of your array, then [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it and [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) every element:

```js
const arr = ['Fruits, Cars, Clothes, Shoes'];

const newArr = arr[0].split(',').map(x => x.trim());

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Note: This will only work if none of the items has a `,` in them: Something like `['foo, foo,bar, bar']` will give `[ 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar' ]`

Comment: Yes obviously, I supposed the separator is `,` and not `, `

Comment: Thank you! That worked