# Add quotes to number values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the values from an array so I can filter them.
Using hints from
[Add single quotes in a string array javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70624591/add-single-quotes-in-a-string-array-javascript) but it doesn't return the whole array with quotes around each value.

Tried:

```
var ages = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_x, i) => i + 1);
console.log(ages); // [1,2,3,4,5]
ages = ages.toString(); 
console.log(ages); // "1,2,3,4,5"
const newArr = ages[0].split(",").map(x => x.trim());
console.log(newArr); // ["1"]
```

//desired: ["1","2","3","4","5",] or ["1","2","3","4","5"]

Comment: `var ages = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_x, i) => String(i + 1));`

Comment: This is an XY-Problem. That's your issue in filtering?

Comment: Thank you. Both answers work. I'm wanting to filter the Array.from (a longer array) [1,2,3...] to a new array of those number that end with (1),(2), etc. I couldn't seem to get it to work without converting ages to string numbers ['1','2', '3'...].

Answer (score 0):

You are over-complicating this, particularly by first converting *the entire* array with `toString()`.  It's as simple as follows:

```
const ages = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_x, i) => i + 1);
const newArr = ages.map(age => age.toString());
console.log(newArr); // [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' ]
```